# The parent DOM element of the data grid has an empty height

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x

```
import React from 'react'
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid'
import Box from '@mui/material/Box'

export default function ManageAdmins() {

  const columns = [
    { field: 'no.', headerName: 'no.' },
    { field: 'id', headerName: 'id' },
    { field: 'avatar', headerName: 'Avatar' },
    { field: 'name', headerName: 'Name' },
    { field: 'active', headerName: 'active?' },
    { field: 'email', headerName: 'Login email' },
    { field: 'contactEmail', headerName: 'Contact email' },
    { field: 'actions', headerName: 'Actions' },
  ]

  return (
    <Box sx={{ height: '500px', width: '500px' }}>
      <DataGrid columns={columns} rows={[]} />
    </Box>
  )
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> MUI: useResizeContainer - The parent DOM element of the data grid has an empty height.
> Please make sure that this element has an intrinsic height.
> The grid displays with a height of 0px.

What's the problem?

Comment: hope [this gitHub issue](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/4911) helps with your case.

Comment: @OmarDieh, I'm actually coming from there. I wish it did

Comment: I have pasted your code in a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-wright-ecp7tf?file=/src/App.js) and It doesn't show the error you are having. maybe check the sadbox mui version and compare it with your local project ? good luck

Comment: @OmarDieh, okay thanks, now I got it, it works as expected on code sandbox, the problem is because I'm rendering the datagrid inside a drawer

Comment: but the problem is I have no idea how to fix this problem now

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error showing Grids in several tabs. The tabs that were not initially open produce this type of error.
What I had initially is something like this:

```
<div> 
    <div style={tabIdx != 1 ? 'hidden' : '' }> <DataGrid .../> </div>
    <div style={tabIdx != 2 ? 'hidden' : '' }> <DataGrid .../> </div>
    <div style={tabIdx != 3 ? 'hidden' : '' }> <DataGrid .../> </div>
</div>
```

So I was rendering all the tabs and DataGrids but showing only one depending on local state variable called tabIdx. In this case, the other two tabs were rendered, but had a width of 0. Thus, producing this error.

I solved this the following way:

```
<div> 
    {tabIdx === 1 ? <div> <DataGrid .../> </div> : null}
    {tabIdx === 2 ? <div> <DataGrid .../> </div> : null}
    {tabIdx === 3 ? <div> <DataGrid .../> </div> : null}
</div>
```

I hope this helps even if it is not exactly the same case.

Answer (score 3):

to solve the issue what you can do is to wrap it in <> </> and conditionally render the conponent

```
const CustomTabPanel = (props: TabPanelProps) => {
const { children, value, index } = props;
return (
  <>
  { value === index ? 
    <div className={styles.gridContainer} 
    id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
    aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
    role="tabpanel">
    {children}
    </div>
 : "" } 
 </>
);
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<DataGrid columns={columns} rows={[]} />
```

to

```
<DataGrid autoheight columns={columns} rows={[]} />
```

Comment: autoheight is different from giving it the full height with a flex box container. When you give it autoheight you'll lose the data virtualization technology used behind the data grid. The data virtualization is the main reason we use datagrids instead of simple tables.